# $\operatorname{arg}$ and $\operatorname{Arg}$, what's the difference?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

So to get the argument of a complex number sometimes we use $$\operatorname{arg}(z)$$ and sometimes we use $$\operatorname{Arg}(z).$$ I didn't know the difference between them so I searched the web. I found that some tutorials, when using $\operatorname{arg}(z)$ add a $2k\pi$ at the end and others do it when using $\operatorname{Arg}(z)$. Now I'm lost! When to use $\operatorname{arg}$ and when to use $\operatorname{Arg}$ ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_%28complex_analysis%29

Comment: Yes I read that, but as I said there are two contradicting views on the web about Arg and arg. Even our professor uses Arg when adding. 2k(pi) I was just asking which one is correct and which one is wrong!

Comment: There is no universally agreed upon definition of Arg. People use different definitions, no definition is more correct than the others.

Comment: The convention I'm more familiar with uses $\operatorname{Arg}$ only for the principal branch, $-\pi < \operatorname{Arg} z < \pi$ for $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0]$, and $\arg$ for an arbitrary branch of the argument. That doesn't mean a different convention is wrong, however. We don't have an academy that defines which definitions are right, mathematics isn't French.

Comment: @DanielFischer. I suggest to create a tag for "irony". Joke, be sure. Cheers.

Comment: So it depends on the definition you set? Thanks guys